# Computer takes abnormally long to POST, boot, or power off

Tags: windows-7, boot, cpu, motherboard, bios

Last night I entered my computer's BIOS to mess with the OC settings on the CPU a bit. Upon saving and booting I encountered a BSOD. I reset and rolled back the changes, however the time it took to POST and boot felt abnormally long, and when I rebooted later on in the day I realized the shutdown time was also terrible. After a cursory Google search I found that resetting the CMOS and setting the SATA mode to AHCI should fix it. I reset it first using only the jumper, then by removing the battery completely, as recommended in the manual, but neither fixed the issue.

I realized that my BIOS version was not the most recent which appears on the Asus support page, however flashing the new BIOS did not fix the issue.

I have also run full virus scans using Bitdefender and Malwarebytes with no results on either.

I decided to test my processor with the Intel Processor Diagnostics tool, where my processor [fails the PCH test](https://pastebin.com/B1PQ01hS), but passes all others.

[image: Results]

I had Prime 95 running overnight (approximately 7 hours) without any error reports of any kind.

I also timed the time it takes to boot from a complete power off state:

- POST: 00:46 (46 seconds)
- Boot Windows 7 to login: 3:36 (3 minutes and
  36 seconds)
- Login to Desktop; 00:25 (25 seconds)

I have not yet recorded the time it takes to power off, but it feels even worse.

I rebooted to install the latest chipset drivers, and the time it took to shut down was only 18 seconds, so the long shut down time may have been a one off incident. The total boot time, however, was 8 minutes.

As I mentioned before, I have already searched for solutions but none seem to apply. If any extra sort of info is necessary I will do what I can. I've also searched Superuser but have not found a solution.

---

Relevant info:

- Mobo: [Asus Z-97P](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1150/Z97-P/E9385_Z97-P.pdf)
- CPU: [i5-4690K](https://ark.intel.com/products/80811/Intel-Core-i5-4690K-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz)
- Bootdrive: Samsung 500GB 850 Evo

Comment: it is plausible there is a problem e.g. in the pagefilearea or something got thrashed during the the corruption that led to the BSOD. One trick is to move the pagefile to a different drive, set the OS disk pagefile to "nothing", and then run a disk check. Afterwards, you can put the pagefile back. Of course, this is an "old" trick that may not bear fruit on an SSD.

Comment: Under what directory would I find the current pagefile?

Comment: it would be in the root of the boot drive, but you would set this via the control panel > system > advanced system settings > advanced tab > advanced tab (!) > virtual memory. You would set it manually to a second drive, possibly reboot, set the c: drive one to "none" reboot, and then the file on the C; drive can be deleted. If you didn't do it right, then it will be locked. Once it is deleted, you can run a chkdsk etc. then remove the temporary pagefile and set it back to "auto"

Comment: Probably will need to set "hide protected operating system files" to false and "show hidden files folder drives" to true in Windows explorer > view > options > view tab

Comment: Unfortunately this did not resolve my problem. After completing all the steps a reboot still took 26 seconds to shut down, 21 seconds to POST, and 4:31 to boot to login. THe Processor test still failed PCH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the culprit was one of my harddrives. I turned off full SATA initialization in the BIOS which greatly reduced POST times but boot times were still bad, presumably because Windows intitializes the harddrives on boot. It had a pending sector to reallocate and was bogging everything down.

The sector has been reallocated now, boot times are not an issue anymore, and I need to look into getting a new harddrive.

So if you have this problem try booting with all unnecesary drives disconnected, and if that resolves the issue plug them in one by one before you boot to find the culprit.